# tigerVNC and XRDP are causing android studio GUI windows to be whited out

Tags: vnc, xrdp

So, I recently deployed an Appium server on a physical dl320 so we can automate our mobile app development. I am using an older version of KVM that only allows one console connection at a time. This is not going to fly, as I need to use it and ill have a QA team connecting in.

It's been a while but after a bit of research, it seems that RDP between windows / Linux is possible. I decided to go with tigerVNC and XRDP, both opensource tools. The setup was easy and I got connected in no time.

The problem is that when I try to start android studio, the GUI windows are white and unusable.

Does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of trial and error, I discovered that tigerVNC has nothing to do with the setup. What the issue is related to is the colour bit depth set in XRDP config file.

To fix:

```
sudo vim /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini
```

add the following lines:

```
param=-depth
param=24
```

at the end of the following section:

```
[Xvnc]
```

The final section should look like:

```
[Xvnc]
param=Xvnc
param=-bs
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-localhost
param=-dpi
param=96
param=-depth
param=24
```

Now RDP from windows to linux is flawless and has enough resolution to actually view the emulators.